# How do I express x in terms of y for the following expression ? $y=2x+\frac{8}{x^2}-5$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

How do I express x in terms of y for the following expression ?

$$y=2x+\frac{8}{x^2}-5$$

The reason I want to do this is to calculate the area between this curve, the y-axis, y=5 and y=1.

I found the answer to be 5 using a roundabout method.

But my first attempt was to try and express x in terms of y.

Basic algebra gave me an expression with an $x^3$.

Comment: Do you want to express x in terms of y?

Comment: Yes Piotr Benedysiuk. I've edited my question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Quick check in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+2x+%2B+8%2Fx%5E2+-5) shows that this isn't an injective function on R. You need to specify the interval of $x$ more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will get really messy if you integrate with respect to y.

Here is what I suggest you do.

$y = 2x + \frac 8{x^2} -5$

Evaluated at $y = 1$ and $y = 5$

$1 = 2x + \frac 8{x^2} -5\\
x = 2$

$5 = 2x + \frac 8{x^2} -5\\
x = 1$

$\int_0^1 (5-1) \;dx + \int_1^2  2x + \frac 8{x^2} -5 - 1\;dx$

Comment: Thanks Doug M , but that is exactly the roundabout method that I mentioned. I'm just wondering if the other method is possible.

Comment: y(x) is not $1-1$ and hence not invertable.  You can find a inverse function over a subset of the domain.  But it is an indication that the algebra is going to be messy.  But... when you have your cubic $x^2 - (5+y)x^2 + 8$ you could pop that into the cubic formula and get an equation for $x$ in terms of $y.$  It will have square roots inside of cube roots (and possibly complex numbers), though.

Comment: Would it be possible if an initial domain of say x from 1 to 2 was given?

Answer (score 2):

Basic algebra is correct.

From
$y=2x+\frac{8}{x^2}-5
$,
multiplying by $x^2$
we get
$yx^2=2x^3+8-5x^2
$,
or
$2x^3-(5-y)x^2+8
= 0
$.

This is,
unfortunately,
a cubic
which can be solved by the
traditionally messy formula.

Its derivative is
$6x^2-2(5-y)x
= 0
$
which has roots
$x=0$
and
$x=\dfrac{5-y}{3}
$.

Note that
at $x=0$
the function is $8$
and at
$\dfrac{5-y}{3}
$
the value is
$2(\frac{5-y}{3})^3-(5-y)(\frac{5-y}{3})^2+8
=(\frac{5-y}{3})^3(2-3)+8
=-(\frac{5-y}{3})^3+8
=(\frac{y-5}{3})^3+8
$.
From this,
we can determine which
values of $y$
give an equation with
$1$ or $3$ real roots.

Answer (score 2):

To find the area, there isn't a particular reason to find $x$ in terms of $y$. A graph of the function shows that the area is relatively simple to find.

[image: Graph thing]

You just have to find the area under your function from $1$ to $2$ (you can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus here), and manipulate it to get your desired area.

Comment: +1 though it is less than clear to me what the question means when it says *"the area between this curve, the y-axis..."*  Incidentally, some of your grey spots are at $(-1,1)$ and $(2\pm\sqrt{8},5)$

Comment: Thank Calconym. I did find the area using your method. It is the roundabout method that I mentioned. My question is not how to find the area. I was just giving some context. My question was how to express x in terms of y, if possible.

Comment: I wouldn't really call it a "roundabout" way then.... But yes, solving for x in terms of y can be helpful to understand it better. Sorry for misunderstanding your question.